# How to upload file to a team site on Sharepoint online (Office 365)

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online

Using C# how do I add a document to a "Documents" web part on a Team Site in SharePoint Online?

I intend to run my code from an intranet.  The code below seems promising but throws a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException.  Cleary I'm not authenticating correctly but where am I going wrong?

```
        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://MyOrg.sharepoint.com/sites/MyTeamSite/"))
        {
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray()) 
                passWord.AppendChar(c);
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("myEmail@MyOrg.com", passWord);
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
            newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
            newFile.Url = "test.txt";

            List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

Comment: This works for me. I had also to install Sharepoint Client Components from here : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35585 and add references to Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client and Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime

Comment: It seems that the version of client components is important, a user is describing the same error message as you and solved it by upgrading the client components : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ddb0690f-3cb0-44f1-a5ed-5852c3daba2e/unable-to-authenticate-to-sharepoint-online-programmatically-with-federated-authentication?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 2):

You code seems ok. But the approach you are using only supports a file less than 2MB. This is due to the way the information is sent from client to the server. The issue is caused by the fact that we are using the Content property of the FileCreationInformation object. If you need upload file larger than 2MB, please look at [Large file upload with CSOM](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.LargeFileUpload) which provides 3 options to upload a large file.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The OP mentions an authentication problem, whereas your solution deals with the size of files.